# Can't log into Windows, mac-spoofing issue or malware?

Tags: windows, malware, mac-spoofing

My computer won't let me log into my account. On the Windows sign in screen it has my account name, but when I put in my password, it always says my password is wrong. No Caps Lock.

This happened just after I configured MadMACs to "Run on Startup" and rebooted Windows! Can MadMACs change/corrupt Windows' login password? I'm using Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

[Here's the MadMACs' source code](https://anonfiles.com/file/3353ebfb1f7bb78b4827d0b2b67b45cb)

I already reinstalled Windows but I'm afraid if it was a malware some data might be stolen (bitcoin wallet and other important stuff).

Comment: Home network or corporate? Active Directory? Installed security software? Do you have network security running on your network? I can reproduce this problem if the MAC changed and my network rejected all communications from the unknown MAC, including connections to the AD server.

Comment: I have looked around for you and found out the program MadMAC's is not-malwareliscious and safe to use.

I also looked around and couldn't find anyone with the same problem you're having, if you really are sure this could happen because of the program, i would verify where you downloaded it (via their site irongeek.com, and not some 3rd party or downloader program). 

Try having an active malware scanner up, some malware scanners can run perfectly next to an antivirus, i personally prefer MSDefender and Malwarebytes.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Well we may never know what the cause was but I would have dropped in the ophcrack livecd and at least checked to see if the password had changed.
[ophcrack live cd](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: -1 because this isn't really an awnser